# Input textbox field allow only characters not allow numeric but allow space?

Tags: javascript

I need help in  textbox field allow only if charcters
i did this function

```
var name = $('.fl-nameinput').val();
rePattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
if (rePattern.test(name.value)) {
    var d = "Your name can only contain alphabets ";
    htm += "<div class='em-full wp-error-msg em-m'>" + d + "</div>" ('.wp-error-msg').css('display', 'block');
}
```

this function type numeric display error message it ok.
but type fully charcter that time also display message.
plz help me.

Comment: `name.value` should be `name`, I think, since you're assigning the `val()` of the `input` to the `name` variable.

Comment: This `htm += "<div class='em-full wp-error-msg em-m'>" + d + "</div>" ('.wp-error-msg').css('display', 'block');` doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Do you ever use a debugger?

Comment: When you enter numeric data , it should display message ??

Answer (score 0):

You are already set `value` for `input`  , so no need to assign `value` again in `if condition`.

**Repalce**

```
if(rePattern.test(name.value) )
```

**With**

```
if(rePattern.test(name) )
```

Comment: hai ,i enter character display error message. enter fully numeric not dipsplay error message.

Comment: means when enter numeric value it should be display error message right ?